# Is there a way to fulfill a promise at an exact time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, promise

I have a web page with transitions, On click everything goes to `opacity:0` ( 1 second duration ) and then a new page is swapped in and everything goes to `opacity:1` ( 1 second duration )

It ends up looking weird if the page doesn't have exactly 1 second to hide and appear. Also if the page doesn't get swapped immediately in between the two it looks award.

This was my first code

```
$('#main').css('opacity', '0');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#main').load('/views/'+name+'.html').css('opacity', '1')
}, 1000);
```

however load() sometimes takes too long to grab the view, and since the css is implemented immediately the opacity is already `1` when it swaps in.

so I tried this:

```
$.get('/views/'+name+'.html', function(page){
    setTimout(function(){
        $('#main').html(page).css('opacity', '1')
    },1000);
})
```

But now if the $.get() is slow, the page is blank for too long. 
Ideally I would like to know how long the promise took to fulfill, and subtract that from the setTimeout time. 
I am thinking now that I have to manually create a new date object and check the difference after promise fulfillment.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot I can just use promises.

```
var pagePromise = $.get('/views/'+name+'.html')

$('main').css('opacity', '0')

setTimeout(function(){
    pagePromise.then(  function(page){ 
       $('main').html(page).css('opacity', '1') } 
    )
},1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get time before and after your request. This may not be exact, but the error margin can easily be ignored for most purposes, yours included.

```
var time = Date.now();
$.get('/views/' + name + '.html', function(page) {
  var elapsed = Date.now() - time;
  setTimout(function() {
    $('#main').html(page).css('opacity', '1')
  }, 1000 - elapsed);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date.now()` and calculate the difference.

```
var start = Date.now();

$.get('/views/' + name + '.html', function(page) {
    setTimout(function() {
       $('#main').html(page).css('opacity', 1);
    }, 1000 - (Date.now() - start));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but attempting to follow your logic, it appears that you want your new content to show up in one second after you hid the old content except when the content takes longer than that to load in which case, it shows up when it's loaded.  You can do that by breaking the process down into a couple steps.

1. Record the starting time.
2. Fetch your content with ajax
3. When the content has been fetched, check how much time has elapsed.
4. If more than a second has elapsed, then just insert the content and show it.
5. If less than a second has elapsed, then set a timer for the remaining amount of time and then show the content when that timer fires.

You can implement that logic like this:

```
var begin = Date.now();
var main = $('#main').css('opacity', '0');
$.get('/views/'+name+'.html').then(function(content) {
    main.html(content);
    var elapsed = Date.now() - begin;
    if (elapsed > 1000) {
        // show it now
        main.css('opacity', '1');
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
            // show it when 1 second has finished
            main.css('opacity', '1');
        }, 1000 - elapsed);
    }
});
```

Using this sort of notification and time measurement scheme, there is no guessing about load times.

Answer (score -4):

You can use ajax and make your code synchronous.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/views/'+name+'.html',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#main').html(page).css('opacity', '1');
    },
    async: false, 
    type: "GET"

});
```

Comment: That is not what OP asked for and `async: false` is just generally bad.

Comment: Generally I wouldn't do async false either but in his situation it makes sense and is more consistent than relying on time based stuff. It is not like he is blocking any click stuff because he is replacing the content of the whole page.

Comment: He doesn't want the animation to run after ajax, he can already easily do that. This doesn't help with the situation in any way.